# How can i fix startx on my RPI3?

Tags: raspbian, boot, linux, login, startx

The day before yesterday I opened too many tabs in the browser, and hung my RPI. I turned it on again with the power turned on. But he was involved not as usual. Instead of having to download the desktop, it has issued the authorization form. Form does not work. If you enter an incorrect login: password you receive an error message if you enter a valid username: password, nothing happens, the screen flashes and the time appears through the same form again requires a login and password.
[image: Screen with login form]
SSH works well. When loading, press *ctrl + shift + f6*, log into the command line and write *sudo startx*, then the desktop is loaded, but not the desktop, on behalf of pi, and the desktop on behalf of the root.
I tried to write *sudo chown -R pi:pi /home/pi*, but it did not help.
How do I fix this error? How to return the usual boot without reinstallation raspbian?

Comment: Don't type `sudo`

Comment: @Milliways i try to _chown -R pi:pi /home/pi_. Without sudo. I reboot and nothing happens. If you mean _startx_ without sudo, it's return error: 
waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

Comment: I was referring to your `sudo startx` which is never going to work. If you have broken something go back to your latest backup - if you don't have one start again.

Comment: @Milliways when i type startx without sudo, i get this error: https://my.mixtape.moe/qffrso.jpg

Answer (score -1):

I fixed. The problem was corrupted bash files in /home/pi. I commented out some lines in them and I was able to boot desktop by pi user.
Thank you all for your attention.